# how to add different images to PHP Live Search result?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, search

My PHP live search code works without any issues. I have added a thumbnail to the drop down search result. The same image (site logo) is added to every search result. Nut now I need to add different images to the drop down search result. Example: facebook live search with different profile pictures.

What I want: Bob's profile picture and details when I type "Bob" in the search box. Mark's profile picture and details to dropdown live search result, when I type "Mark" in search box.

I'm only posting my search.php file here. I think it's enough for my question. This code adds one thumbnail (image.jpg) to all dropdown live search results. How to add different thumbnails to each results?

```
<?php
include('db.php');
if($_POST)
{
    $q = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search']);
    $strSQL_Result = mysql_query("select id,name,email from live_search where name like '%$q%' or email like '%$q%' order by id LIMIT 5");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($strSQL_Result))
    {
        $username   = $row['name'];
        $email      = $row['email'];
        $b_username = '<strong>'.$q.'</strong>';
        $b_email    = '<strong>'.$q.'</strong>';
        $final_username = str_ireplace($q, $b_username, $username);
        $final_email = str_ireplace($q, $b_email, $email);
        ?>
            <div class="show" align="left">
                <img src="image.jpg" style="style here"><?php echo $final_username; ?></span>&nbsp;<br/><?php echo $final_email; ?><br/>
            </div>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I have resolved my question.The simplest way is to name the thumbnail either "$username.jpg" or "$user_id.jpg". Something that is unique between the users.
Then just do:     `<img src="profiles/thumbnail_<?php echo $user_id; ?>.jpg" ... />`